# TXT file search and delete

Tags: php

A (simple) question.
I have a TXT file search script in PHP.

```
$search = $_GET["search"];
$logfile = $_GET['logfile'];
// Read from file 
$file = fopen($logfile, "r");
?> <head> <title>Searching: <?php echo $search ?></title> </head> <?php
while( ($line =  fgets($file) )!= false)
{
if(stristr($line,$search))   // case insensitive
echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr>";
}
fclose($file);
```

Now what I want to do is delete all the text it finds in the TXT file.
I tried doing a str_replace but it didn't work.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You need to basically rewrite the file.

Comment: Can you not just `unlink()` it?

Comment: Please add it to the code, would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the magic:

```
$file->ftruncate($file->ftell());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to gather the lines which doesn't contain the search term and you need to save the text in an array.

When you're done with the listing, you need to open the file in write mode (which will empty the file) and then write the text you gathered in the file.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$search = isset($_GET["search"]) ? $_GET["search"] : '';
$logfile = isset($_GET['logfile']) ? $_GET['logfile'] : '';
$text_without_term_arr = array();
if(!empty($logfile) && !empty($search)){
    // Read from file
    $file = fopen($logfile, "r");
    echo '  <head>
                <title>Searching: ' . $search . '</title>
            </head>';
    while(($line = fgets($file))!== false){
        if(stristr($line, $search)){
            // Case insensitive search
            echo '<font face="Arial">' . $line . '</font><hr/>';
        } else {
            // Search term not found in these lines
            array_push($text_without_term_arr, $line);
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
    // Empty the file and write the text again without the search term
    if(!empty($text_without_term_arr)){
        $new_file = fopen($logfile, "w");
        $content = implode("\n", $text_without_term_arr);
        fwrite($new_file, $content);
        fclose($new_file);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another file handle to write the result out to:

```
$tempname=tmpname('/tmp','result');
$outfile=fopen($tempname,'w');
```

Next, use `str_ireplace` to remove the found text in each line:

```
$newline=str_ireplace($search, '', $line);
```

Then write the new line out to the out file:

```
fputs($outfile,$newline); // May need to send PHP_EOL too
```

Close the file off:

```
fclose($outfile);
```

And then rename the new file to the old filename:

```
rename($tempname,$logfile);
```